# Subclass the Marker Class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is there no way to extend the Marker class? Markers are the pins on a google maps map in android.
The only class i can extend is the MarkerOptionsCreator class.

Comment: I don't know about the google maps API, but maybe Marker is an interface?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

One of the reasons of wanting to do this is because I need a reference to my markers after their added. I dynamically create Markers depending on the data in a database. Then show them grouped on a buttonclick event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to extend the `Marker` class. It's final.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect info about a markers in a HashMap when adding them to a map. For example:

```
mHashMap.put(mKey, mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("mTitle")))
```